# Python profiler does not exit with proper exit code

Tags: python, bash, profiling, pytest, cprofile

I am profiling a python script using cProfile and I want it to have the same exit code as my script's exit code.

Let's say my script *error.py* is:

```
import sys

print ("Error")
sys.exit(1)
```

Of course when I run it with:

```
python3 error.py
```

the process exits with a code 1, but when I run it with following command:

```
python3 -m cProfile error.py
```

The exit code is 0 and I want to propagate the exit code of *error.py* to the profiler.

Is there a way to achieve that?

---

EDIT

Applying pkqxdd 's suggestions helped but my problem is more complex.
*error.py* is now:

```
print ("Error")
raise Exception
```

However, I am using cProfile together with py.test-3 as following:

```
 python3 -m cProfile -o profile $(which py.test-3) error.py
```

The command above still produces the exit code 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no

Because a non-zero exit code from profiler means there is an error while running the profiler. It's not the profiler's job to check your script's exit code. However, you can raise an exception if the exit code is all you care about:

```
# error.py
raise Exception
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my problem is more complex so I edited the original post. Hope you can help with that as well.

Comment: @Konrad Now you have an entirely different problem. The pytest module catches all exceptions while executing the code. Even though it exits non-zero, as I have stated in my answer, it's not the profiler's job to check your script's exit code. The profiler simply doesn't care (check) your exit code.